# Azure Application Insights - get the list of apps and its IDs

Tags: azure, api, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I am trying to get the list of Application Insights applications to get the list of app insights IDs for PowerBI use. I will need this IDs put in a slicer/dropdown, but I cannot seem to get the list of apps and the IDs.

API does not have an endpoint where I can get the list of App Insights apps.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are all the application insights in the same subscription? and which language are your using, c# or others?

Comment: Yes IvanYang, all application insights are on the same subscription

Comment: Hi jeff, please see the answer below :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [application insights Components - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/list) rest api.

You can test it by click the Try it button on the page:

[image]

**Then** it lists all the application insights, includes name / app id etc.:

[image]

Comment: sometimes its just hard to get thru the docs alone, its like finding a needle in a haystack. answers like this is golden